# Mono Xamarin App Development

Tags: .net, mvvm, cross-platform, prism, xamarin

I have recently been tasked with architecting a rebuild of our large web application into a cross-platform installable application covering WPF, iOS, Android, and Surface. Here is what I plan on using:

MVVM Architecture with Prism framework
Unity IoC (included with Prism)
SQLite and SQLite-NET ORM for local storage
Library for making REST service calls (TBD)

Given the large scope of this application, Prism and Unity make sense to use. My question is, has anyone successfully used these libraries in cross platform apps using Xamarin? If these are too large and do not port well, what are some alternatives?

For an IoC, I have seen TinyIoc mentioned on the Xamarin site, but have also seen that it is for small sized projects, which mine is not.

Have seen where people have used MVVM Light, but again, I've seen it stated that this is for use in smaller applications.

Since this is my first time architecting a multi-platform application, I want to make sure I have the right tools for the job. So any experience, alternatives, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just seeing MVVM and Unity (MVVM more so) in this mix is enough to cause chills, and adding WPF to the mix doesn't help. I'm working on a Xamarin-based app that has to work on Android (eventually) and some web services. Nothing of enormous size but enough to know you'll have headaches MVVM-ing the UI. How dynamic is your UI? Would you share a rough abstract description of what are you doing?

Comment: @Sten: The app will be used as a health assessment tool. Assessments can take anywhere from 10 minutes to 2 hours. There is also reports that are accessible. From what I've seen, Xamarin uses the MVVMCross library so MVVM shouldn't be an issue. I am hoping to create a ViewModel that any platform UI can wire up to. The UI itself is not dynamic, but I was wanting to use prism to be able to utilize different view models and be able to plug pieces into shell views.

Comment: The problem with cross platform and iOS / Android are bindings.  They work great in xaml but don't exist for iOS / Android.  That's where MVVMCross comes in.

Comment: @Derek: Yeah, I've been looking into MvvmCross the last couple days and it seems like a good option. From what I read, Xamarin is supposed to be announcing support for PCLs at the conference next month and Slodge put a tutorial out on CodeProject for getting MvvmCross set up. Unfortunately, I have to use .NET 4.0 instead of 4.5 but will hopefully not struggle getting this set up.